# Assert outside a try/catch in obj-c

Tags: objective-c, assert

Today I think i might have learned something (not sure), i'm not really a obj-c programmer, more the php & java type, but building a iPhone app together with somebody got me this, so hopefully somebody can help me explain what and why:

I've put some code inside a `@try {..}` and `@catch (NSException * e) {..}` and my thought was everything would have been caught by that, but the other developer put and `assert(false);` at the end of the function, after de catch.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`assert(3)` is not part of Objective-C itself.  It's part of the C standard.  Check out the [man page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/assert.3.html).  From the C spec, section **7.2.1.1 The `assert` macro**:

> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
>     #include <assert.h>
>     void assert(scalar expression);
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> The **`assert`** macro puts diagnostic tests into programs; it expands to a void expression. When it is executed, if **`expression`** (which shall have a scalar type) is false (that is, compares equal to 0), the **`assert`** macro writes information about the particular call that failed (including the text of the argument, the name of the source file, the source line number, and the name of the enclosing function — the latter are respectively the values of the preprocessing macros **`__FILE__`** and **`__LINE__`** and of the identifier **`__func__`**) on the standard error stream in an implementation-defined format. It then calls the **`abort`** function.

So `assert(false)` will just crash the program at that point.

Comment: ok, so the program crashes when it gets outside the catch, but that was my whole point, to NOT let it crash and catch everything :) that's why I don't understand his assert that's outside the catch...

Comment: Without seeing the code, that's hard to say, I'm afraid.  You might have to get in touch with this other programmer.